# Is there a Jquery plugin that will do a Image Carousel/slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

For example:

**Prev**  IMAGE1 IMAGE2 IMAGE3 IMAGE4  **Next**

And then...when thee person clicks next, it will change to:

**Prev**    IMAGE5 IMAGE6 IMAGE7 IMAGE8    **Next**

And ideally, it would have a "slide to the left" effect.
Does anyone know if there is a JQuery plugin that does this?

THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Answer (score 1):

Yep, knock yourself out:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/